# Looking for the folder location of where Google Chrome bookmarks are stored on Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, storage, bookmarks

I'm looking to manually back up and restore the Google Chrome mobile bookmarks on my LG smartphone and wanted to know the folder and filepath of where they are stored on Android. I checked in /data/data/com.android.chrome/ but nothing is there. I do not have my bookmarks synced to my Google account so am unsure where they are stored on the device. I could not find this info anywhere online. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: */data/user/0/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Bookmarks*

Comment: Addition to alecxc's comment: this directory is only accessible with root permissions.